# Check if a sub-view is reloaded; angularjs, ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in angular js to nest views. A directive in one of my parent views requires to watch if a sub-view is reloaded. Can anyone tell me how would I watch if a sub-view inside a view is reloaded?

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
  <header myDirective></header>
  <div id="content" ui-view name="bodyContent"></div>
</body>
```

Directive JS

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
return function(scope,element,attr){
    scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
        element.on("click", function(){
            // do something
        });

        element.parent().find('#content').on("click", function(){
            //do something
        })
    });
};
})
```

Here, the `$watch` statement only watches the parent view load. What I need to do is to add the event listener for `#content` everytime the sub view (bodyContent) is changed or reloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by making use of *[State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)* of angular. Here is how I solved the problem:

So far, I had been watching the $viewContentLoaded variable of the parent view, which wasnt of much help. I had to watch the $viewContentLoaded variable of the child View. So, first I checked for "State Change Success" using `scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState ))` 
Here, the variable `event` is important. It has a `targetScope` variable which is of our concern.
Now all I did was watched the `$viewContentLoaded` variable of the targetScope and add event listener on that. The code looks like this

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return function(scope,element,attr){
        scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState){
            event.targetScope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
                element.on("click", function(){
                    // do something
                });

                element.parent().find('#content').on("click", function(){
                    //do something
                })
            })

        });
    };
})
```

I hope others will be benefited by this. :)

Comment: could you please add a code pen or jsfiddle example for this ?

Comment: Nice solution, there should really be a default method to do this in ui.router.